# How to spread monthly values over biweekly pay periods in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have values each month of the year.  They sum to 1.0.

```
 O   N   D   J   F   M   A   M   J   J   A   S
.05 .06 .20 .05 .05 .05 .05 .05 .18 .16 .05 .05
```

I want to spread these out proportionally over biweekly pay periods.  The sum should remain 1.0 (or close)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
x x x x x x x x x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

Can anyone think of a formula or method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create a cell for each day of the year, calculating the pay fraction from the monthly values. Then add those up over each biweekly period to get your fortnightly values.